# VS2008 'Show all files'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, projects-and-solutions

I wonder if anybody has any suggesting for an ongoing vs2008 frustration of mine. The chaps at Microsoft HQ, in their wisdom, have deemed that some project types are not worthy of the ‘show all files’ option on the project explorer. Database projects are an example of this. Does anybody know of a method (registry hack, etc) of forcing the option to work?

I would really appreciate any answer, I find it incredibly annoying.